# django test views that involve invocation of a signal

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have 2 apps, 1 for auth and the other for storing profile related info

**auth app**
*models.py*

```
class User(AbstractUser):
      # contains the User related info
```

*signals.py*

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_related_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
if instance and created:
    instance.profile = Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

**profiles app**
*models.py*

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # other info
```

while testing update user method.

```
class TestUserRetrieveUpdateView(APITestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.test_username = 'testuser'
    self.test_email = 'test@example.com'
    self.test_password = 'testpassword'
    # We want to go ahead and originally create a user.
    self.test_user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(self.test_username,
                                                          self.test_email, self.test_password)

    self.auth_headers = {'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': f"Bearer {self.test_user.token}"}
    # URL for creating an account.
    self.detail_url = reverse('users:detail')

    # URL for creating an account.
    self.create_url = reverse('users:signup')

    # Request factory
    self.request_factory = RequestFactory()

@patch('yapoll.users.signals.create_related_profile')
def test_udpate_user_with_preexisting_username(self, mock):

    data_1 = {
        'username': 'testuser2',
        'email': 'test_1@example.com',
        'password': 'testuser'
    }

    response_1 = self.client.post(self.create_url, data_1, format='json')
    data = {'username': 'testuser2'}
    # TODO: Complete this test case handling signals
    response = self.client.put(self.detail_url, data, format='json', **self.auth_headers)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    self.assertEqual(get_user_model().objects.count(), 2)
    self.assertTrue('errors' in response.data)
    self.assertTrue('username' in response.data['errors'])
    self.assertEqual(len(response.data['errors']['username']), 1)
```

While doing this I am the getting the following error.
django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no profile.

However, I have tested the user creation and profile creation subsequently using signals. It's working fine.

Comment: You have to cerate a Profile instance for your user.

Comment: should I do that explicitly? On creation of the user, the signal should invoke the creation of profile? Please check the post_save signal in the signals.py in section of auth app in the first few lines.

Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems:

1.You receiver is not calling save on the instance, so after you assign `instance.profile` it is not saving those changes to the database.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_related_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance and created:
        instance.profile = Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.save()
```

2.Another *potential* issue may be when you create and assign the user to `test_user` in your tests.  When you call `create_user` it returns the instance as it was saved, which does not have a profile assigned because the profile was assigned after it was created in the receiver.  You can use `self.test_user.refresh_from_db()` to update the instance with any new data in the database, which in this case would retrieve the profile added to the instance in your post_save signal.

```
self.test_user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
    self.test_username,
    self.test_email, 
    self.test_password
)
#  print(self.test_user.profile)  # this would fail or print None
self.test_user.refresh_from_db()
#  print(self.test_user.profile)  # Now this should print the profile object
```

Comment: I am not getting this while trying to update the user with a different username, while calling this method -  response = self.client.put(self.detail_url, data, format='json', **self.auth_headers). 

It's a HTTP request. however, I think it's being called even before the create action is completed.